# Code to Restart , Shutdown and enter in to Download Mode for Android Phones?

Tags: android, shutdown, reboot

Hi all I am just curious to find out some code that can pro-grammatically ***REBOOT*** , ***SHUTDOWN*** and enter in to ***DOWNLOAD MODE*** mobile phones with. I have been exhausted scouring the internet to find something to do with this but have failed. Does any one have any ideas/links/references ?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is signed with the system key, you can use [reboot()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot%28java.lang.String).

On the other hand, if you have root you can still do it (this doesn't work on a few ROMs, mainly a few stock HTC ones.

Shutdown:

```
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Restart:

Same code, just use `reboot` instead of `reboot -p`.

AFAIK, it is not possible to boot into "Download Mode" using any API, but on a rooted device you may be able to do it using the `adb` binary

Comment: For some reason when I try to put this in this does not work at all the code you have supplied me with has not given me anything I am using a Samsung Phone will this be a problem ?

Comment: you have showed me the reboot() but is there anyway of implementing it with some sort of code as it is not there on the android site

Comment: @Mizzeeboy The code I gave will only work on a rooted device. And the reboot method only works if you have your app signed by the manufacturer of the ROM

Comment: but I don't understand you haven't given me a reboot method I would appreciate it if you could jot it down in your answer section

Comment: @Mizzeeboy The reboot method is part of the system. You just call it.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by calling the reboot method? could u just show me what it is?